# vertex paint seems to be "low res" or weird on some parts of the mesh

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, vertex-paint

This seems to be a problem of the mesh or the UVs because it also happens on weight paint. But I don't know what to do. the left object seems to work somewhat fine but the right side is just too bad, I can't paint properly paint on that side.
I tried redoing the UVs and it's still the same.

[image]

Comment: Vertex Paint and Weight Paint will completely depend on your topology, so if you have for example stretched faces the vertex paint will appear stretched, maybe it's the case here?

Comment: What moonboots said, and to add: vertex paint is completely independent of UV.  You might consider creating and painting a UV mapped texture instead, to make your colors (relatively) independent of the topology/vertex density.